# Calling a method in main class from non main class

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

I have two Java classes:

BoardManager & 
Board

BoardManager is the main class. Inside it contains a board:

```
    public BoardManager(){
        Board b = new Board();
    }

    public methodToBeCalled(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BoardManager();
    }
```

Board is the user interface. When a user presses a button on the interface I want it to then call a method in the BoardManager class, but that obviously presents a problem and I am unsure how to get around it.

One solution was to move the main method into Board and so this:

```
BoardManager boardManager;

    public Board(){}

    public void buttonPressed(){
        boardManager.methodToCall();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boardManager = new BoardManager();
    }
```

But that just throw up errors about static and unstatic etc.

Solutions? Thanks!

Comment: You can't call a method in a static context from a non-static context.

Comment: You could pass BoardManager reference to Board, i.e. Board b = new Board(this); then Board would be aware of its parent, and could call its methods, but you should think twice before creating class dependancies.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Mike, could you elaborate on "class dependencies"? What would be a better solution?

Comment: There's no problem with it if it does the job :P

Comment: This is what I did: I have BoardManager is the main class which creates a Board and passes itself through like you said, Board b = new Board(this). In Board, I have BoardManager bManager, but when I tried to call methods I got "local variable bManager is accessed within inner class; needs to be declared final". It is working now after setting bManager to final, but this just seems like a very messy solution :S

Answer (score 0):

Either this:

```
class Board{
static BoardManager boardManager;

public Board(){}

public void buttonPressed(){
    boardManager.methodToCall();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boardManager = new BoardManager();
}
}
```

Or this:

```
class Board {
BoardManager boardManager;

public Board(){ }

public void buttonPressed(){
    boardManager.methodToCall();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board b = new Board();
    b.boardManager = new BoardManager();
}
}
```

You can't call a non-static field(BoardManager) from a static method (main). Read more about the **static** keyword.